# Добавление элемента в двумерный ассоциативный массив php

Tags: php

Как в этот массив добавить значение

```
        $arr = ["2020-05" => [1,2,3]];
```

чтобы получилось так:

```
        $arr = ["2020-05" => [1,2,3,4]];
```

Answer (score 0):

в первый элемент

```
$arr = ["2020-05" => [1,2,3]];
$arr[key($arr)][] = 4;
print_r($arr);
```

в элемент с известным вам индексом

```
$arr["2020-05"][] = 4;
```